# Dapper multiselect: Nested class primary key doesn't map unless using "AS"

Tags: c#, .net, sql, dapper

I have two classes:

```
class Foo{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    ...
    public Bar Bar { get; set }
}

class Bar{
    public int BarId { get; set; }
    public int FooId { get; set }
    ...
}
```

when i then run the query like this:

```
sqlConnection.Query<Foo, Bar, Foo>(
    "SELECT * FROM Foo JOIN Bar ON Foo.FooId = Bar.FooId",
    (foo, bar) => { 
         foo.Bar = bar;
         return foo; 
       }, 
    splitOn: "FooId");
```

the result would then be that all properties on both Foo and Bar will map up Except for Bar.BarId.
After checking the column name and type in the database against my Bar class I still couldn't find any differences.

One strange thing I stumbled upon was that if I wrote:

```
"SELECT *, BarId AS BarId FROM Foo JOIN Bar ON Foo.FooId = Bar.FooId"
```

Bar.BarId actually mapped as expected, have I misunderstood how to use Dapper or is this a bug?

Comment: From your classes definition it seems you're having a 1-to-1 relation... Is that actually the case or you've oversimplified your code example?

Comment: @Robert Koritnik it's actually a 1-to-(0 or 1) relation, and yes that is actually the case.

Comment: In that case it should actually be a `left join`, but never mind the details.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik yes, you are correct, I missed this when I wrote the example (I didn't copy paste), well spotted none the less!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is trying to do a split on `FooId`, so every time it sees `FooId` it is cutting the data. This use-case is *essentially* intended for the (not uncommon) scenario where all the tables have a predictable key such as `Id`. In your case, this is not what you want, as you get from the database:

```
FooId, a, b, c | BarId, FooId, x, y, z
^^ from Foo ^^ | ^^ from Bar ^^
```

However, that splits on `FooId` as:

```
FooId, a, b, c, BarId | FooId, x, y, z
```

which is why `BarId` doesn't get included in the second object, and also why adding it to the end makes it work.

There is another usage, IIRC, that accepts the *sequenced* keys to split on; you would use:

```
splitOn: "FooId,BarId"
```

Comment: That makes so much more sense, thank you for the clarification and the nice visualization of the problem!

Comment: @Joakim thanks for including enough detail in the question so I could understand exactly what was happening ;p

Comment: @Mark: Could you add an additional sentance/paragraph explaining how those *sequenced keys* work differently cause it's definitely not obvious (or I'm just so daft)?