# How do I get multi-mapping to work in Dapper?

Tags: ado.net, dapper

I am trying to do the following with Dapper (and failing).

My POCOs (all code simplified) are:

```
    public class Company
    {
        public int CompanyId { get; private set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; private set; }
        public Person CompanyAddress { get; private set; }
        public Person Administrator { get; private set; }
}
    public class Person
    {
        public int PersonId { get; private set; }
        public string FirstName { get; private set; }
        public string LastName { get; private set; }
}
```

In the database the Company table has a FK for CompanyAddress and Administrator which maps to the PersonID PK in the Person table. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705270/dapper-multiselect-nested-class-primary-key-doesnt-map-unless-using-as?rq=1) and [this](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#multi-mapping) I think the follwoing is how I want to do this:

```
public static Company Select(IDbConnection connection, int id)
{
    Trap.trap();
    return connection.Query<Company, Person, Person, Company>("select * from Company left join Person address on Company.CompanyAddress = address.PersonId left join Person admin on Company.Administrator = admin.PersonId where Company.CompanyId = @Id",
        (cmpy, addr, admin) => new { PersonId = id }).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

But that gives me a compile error on the "new { PersonId = id }". What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the `SplitOn` parameter to specify where the next table/class starts. You also shouldn't create an anonymous type but use a new scope to initialize the `Administrator` property of `Company`:

```
string sql = @"select c.CompanyId,c.CompanyName, c.CompanyAddress,
                      address.PersonId, etc. ....
               from Company c
               left join Person address 
                  on Company.CompanyAddress = address.PersonId 
               left join Person admin 
                  on Company.Administrator = admin.PersonId 
               where Company.CompanyId = @Id";
string splitOn = "PersonId"; // maybe two parameters separated by comma, see comment below the answer
return connection.Query<Company, Person, Person, Company>(sql,
    (Company cmpy, Person addr, Person admin) => { cmpy.Administrator = admin; return cmpy; }
    ,null,null,true,splitOn)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

However, i'm not sure if that works already since you have two joins to the same table. So i think you need an alias for all of the duplicate columns like `PersonId`. But this migt be helpful anyway.

Comment: That gives an error the @Id needs to be defined. I'm giving up on Dapper, I've spent more time trying to get this to work than it would have taken to just handle the select myself. And using up your time too - sorry.